# Would you start a new project and store files in a Java Content Repository?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jcr

I need to store uploaded files in my web app. Database seems to be wrong even though someone says it is just fine. Uploading the files to the local filesystem of the app container is not scaleable. So from what I know the only option I have is JCR and I wonder if you would use it in a new project today? What are the options? (links would be great)

Comment: Why is it not scaleable? Storing them as flat files on the local machine is the same as storing them as blobs in a local database. If you want to store them on a remote database, then that's a different story.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How would you store the files?

Comment: In an app I'm working on, we have files stored on the file system which we serve directly to users requesting them. There are thousands files (but not necessarily large, mostly configs). It's a content delivery server, so I would ask you what your reqs are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) to serve files in a clustered application.